# I have Created a VR player using Google Cardboard SDK and Easy Movie Texture plugin in Unity

Tags: c#, android, video, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I have Created a VR video player using Google Cardboard SDK and Easy Movie Texture plugin in Unity.
I want to add control buttons like play,pause ,stream like a normal video player.
Anybody knows how it can be implemented ?

noob at Unity. Need a great help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the magnetic sliding trigger at the cardboard's side to allow the user to toggle a menu, and use the phone's gyroscope or compass to track user rotation and allow the user to select Play/Pause etc... A nod of the head, detectable by the phone's accelerometer, will be used to confirm an action.

Use the `Cardboard.SDK.OnTrigger` event provided by the Google Cardboard API to detect the magnetic trigger pull in your script as such:

```
void OnEnable() {
    Cardboard.SDK.OnTrigger += triggerPulledEvent;
}

void triggerPulledEvent() {
    menuOpen = !menuOpen;//Toggle the menu
}
```

Then, poll the mobile device for sensors:

To select option based on head rotation:

```
Input.compass.enabled = true;

int totalOptions = 3;//Play, pause, exit
int selectionNumber = Input.compass.magneticHeading / 360 * totalOptions;

enum Options {
    PLAY = 0, PAUSE = 1, EXIT = 2//Add more as needed
}
```

Of course, you'll need to display the current option the user is looking at, but I'll leave it to you.

For the accelerometer to detect nod, check for a significant value acceleration in the Y axis:

```
if(Math.Abs(Input.acceleration.y) > 13) {
    ConfirmOption();
}

void ConfirmOption() {
    //Code that plays, pauses, stops the video etc
}
```